# Foreign Keys in SailsJS Models and Databases

Tags: javascript, foreign-keys, sails.js, models

I've been trying to get a better understanding of how to setup Foreign Keys in SailsJS. I am currently working on a project for class in which my group needs to create an evaluation system with instructor and students profile to view the results. I've seen some examples online, but I have seen varies formats and I'm not sure what the correct format is suppose to look like.

User Model

```
/**
* User.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    // The user's anonymous ID (e.g. 1)
    anonymousID: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true
    },

    // The user's first name (e.g. Bob)
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    //The user's last name (e.g. Smith)
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },

    // The user's full name (e.g. Bob Smith)
    fullName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    // The user's assigned NetID (e.g. abc123)
    netID: {
        type: 'string',
        primaryKey: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    // The user's nine digit SchoolID (e.g. 000-000-000)
    schoolID: {
        type: 'integer',
        size: 9,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    // The user's email address (e.g. netID@university.edu)
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        email: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    // The encrypted password for the user (e.g. asdgh8a249321e9dhgaslcbqn2913051#T(@GHASDGA)
    encryptedPassword: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    // The timestamp when the the user last logged in
    // (i.e. sent a username and password to the server)
    lastLoggedIn: {
      type: 'date',
      required: true,
      defaultsTo: new Date(0)
    },

    // The user's academic title (e.g. student)
    title: {
        state:{
            type : 'string',
            required: true,
            enum: ['Student', 'Faculty', 'Staff', 'Dean'],
        defaultsTo: 'Staff'
        }
    },

    // The user's academic classification (e.g. freshman)
    classification: {
        state: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            enum: ['Freshman', 'Sophomore', 'Junior', 'Senior', 'Graduate', 'N/A']
        defaultsTo: 'N/A'
        }
    },

  }
};
```

Schedule Model

```
/**
* Schedule.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    // The CRN ID (e.g. 32458)
    courseID: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    // The Course Reference Name (e.g. MBW 1001)
    course: {
        type: 'string',
        size: 8,
        required: true
        // Add FK code from Course Table
    },

    // The Course Name (e.g. Magical Basket Weaving)
    title: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
        // Add FK code from Course Table
    },

    // The Course Instructor (e.g. ab123)
    intructorID: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
        // Add FK code from User Table
    },

    // The Term refers to the semester (e.g. Fall 2015)
    term: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
  }
};
```

Courses Model

```
/**
* Course.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    // The Evaluation ID (e.g. 1)
    courseNum: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true
    },

    // The Department Name (e.g. Arts and Sciences)
    department: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    // The Course Reference Name (e.g. MBW 1001)
    course: {
        type: 'string',
        primaryKey: true,
        size: 8,
        unique: true
    },

    // The Course Name (e.g. Magical Basket Weaving)
    title: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

  }
};
```

Enrolled Model

```
/**
* Enrolled.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    // The Transaction ID (e.g. 32458)
    transactionID: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    // The CRN ID (e.g. 32458)
    courseID: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true
      // Add FK code from Schedule Table
    },

    // The Course Instructor (e.g. ab123)
    instructorID: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
        // Add FK code from Schedule Table
    },

    // The Course Instructor (e.g. ab123)
    studentID: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
        // Add FK code from User Table
    },

    // The Term refers to the semester (e.g. Fall 2015)
    term: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    // The Right to Submit an Evaluation (e.g. True or False)
    evaluationStatus: {
        type: 'boolean',
    },
  }
};
```

Evaluation Model

```
/**
* Evaluation.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    // The Evaluation ID (e.g. 1)
    evaluationID: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    // The user's anonymous ID (e.g. 1)
    anonymousID: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        // Add FK code from user table
    },

    // The Course Instructor (e.g. ab123)
    intructorID: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
        // Add FK code from User Table
    },

    // The course's assigned CRN (e.g. 12343)
    courseID: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 5
        // Add FK code from schedule table
    },

    // The Course Reference Name (e.g. MBW 1001)
    course: {
        type: 'string',
        size: 8,
    },

    // The rating of question 1
    ratingOne: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 2
    ratingTwo: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 3
    ratingThree: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 4
    ratingFour: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 5
    ratingFive: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 6
    ratingSix: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 7
    ratingSeven: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 8
    ratingEight: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 9
    ratingNine: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The rating of question 10
    ratingTen: {
        type: 'integer',
        required: true,
        size: 2
    },

    // The positive feedback from student
    positiveFeedback: {
        type: 'string',
        defaultsTo: 'N/A',
        size: 4000
    },

    // The negative feedback from student
    negativeFeedback: {
        type: 'string',
        defaultsTo: 'N/A',
        size: 4000
    },

    // The General Rating of Evaluation (e.g. 8.76, SUM(ratings)/TotalRatings)
    genRateEval: {
        type: 'float',
        required: true,
        size: 4
    },

    // The Inaproprate Flag (e.g. True or False)
    inaproprateFlag: {
        type: 'boolean',
    },
  }
};
```

I've included all five models I'm working with so everyone can get a complete picture of how everything will/should connect.

From my understanding, the foreign key should be setup like the code snippet below.

Schedule Model (with Foreign Keys)

```
/**
* Schedule.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    // The CRN ID (e.g. 32458)
    courseID: {
        type: 'integer',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    // The Course Reference Name (e.g. MBW 1001)
    course: {
        // Add FK code from Course Table
      model: 'Course',
      via: 'course'
    },

    // The Course Name (e.g. Magical Basket Weaving)
    title: {
        // Add FK code from Course Table
      model: 'Course',
      via: 'title'
    },

    // The Course Instructor (e.g. ab123)
    intructorID: {
        // Add FK code from User Table
      model: 'User',
      via: 'netID'
    },

    // The Term refers to the semester (e.g. Fall 2015)
    term: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
  }
};
```

I'm not completely sure though if that's the proper way to setup foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its the right way of setting up a foreign key in sails js. That being said, it varies on the type of association i.e., whether the relation is one to one or one to many.

Taking the examples from sailsjs website,

**One to One relation:**

`myApp/api/models/pet.js`

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name:'STRING',
        color:'STRING',
        owner:{
            model:'user'
        }
    }

}
```

`myApp/api/models/user.js`

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name:'STRING',
        age:'INTEGER',
        pony:{
            model: 'pet'
        }
    }

}
```

**One to Many relation:** 
`myApp/api/models/pet.js`

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name:'STRING',
        color:'STRING',
        owner:{
            model:'user'
        }
    }

}
```

`myApp/api/models/user.js`

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name:'STRING',
        age:'INTEGER',
        pets:{
            collection: 'pet',
            via: 'owner'
        }
    }

}
```

[Sailsjs Associations](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is how to use association so first use the reference/documentation on the sails js official website http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations, and i think all your queries will be solved.